# screen size in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i would like to change the screen size so that sprites will disappear before they reach the real screen edges.

BUT i still want my background to stay on all of the screen size.

Imagine a paper on my screen so i want to game to exist only on that paper, and around that paper there still will be some background.

so, how do i set my `CCSprites` to move in and out from that paper and slowly disappear when coming to its edges ?

my sprites are moves with : (i need to put some code to get published cause site "standard" )

```
id moveclouds1 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:30 position:ccp(420,380)];
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use glscissor for that
simply subclass a CCLayer to make your "paper screen". Then add you sprites inside this layer.
on this layer override the visit method

```
- (void) visit
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

glScissor(x,y, width, height); //here put the position and the size of the paper/screen

[super visit];
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glPopMatrix();

}
```

a sprite reaching the border of the paper/screen will be scissored off. 
REMEMBER: glScissor will use PIXEL values not points, so it`s your job to use double values for retina display ( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() can come in handy )